# Adding Typescript to existing Node/Express Javascript application

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am just adding Typescript to our Node / Express backend.  I had existing ESLint setup but after adding Typescript it now causes problems with linting `.js` files and I actually have no errors any longer for my `.js` files.

The goal is to slowly move over existing `.js` files to `.ts` but with the project size and my current bandwidth can't do it all at once.  So I'm taking the slow approach of anything new using Typescript and whenever I touch an old piece of code, rewriting that in Typescript as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

My `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
      "no-console": "off",
      "comma-dangle": "error",
      "semi": "error"
  },
  "overrides": {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "airbnb-typescript", "prettier/@typescript-eslint"],
      "plugins": ["prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  }
}
```

I also have `.pretierrc`

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 200,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

Here are my dev dependencies for `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.33",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.14",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.10.3",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-async-await": "0.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "link-module-alias": "^1.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.8",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "mockgoose": "^8.0.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sinon": "^9.2.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

Comment: That sounds like a sane approach to me. What is the question here?

Comment: The question is that that the linter doesn't seem to be working.  I still want to lint `.js` files but not using the same rules set as the `.ts` files.  Right now its using the typescript ruleset to lint the javascript files causing obvious issues

Answer (score 0):

You can tell you ESLint to ignore all the JavaScript files by creating a `.eslintignore` file, it works in a similar way of `gitignore`.

For ex: You `.eslintignore` may looks like :

```
build/*.js
model/*.js
```

Don't forget to restart your Editor.

Comment: won't this not allow the `.js` files to be linted at all.  I'm looking for some solution that allows two different rulesets.  Lint to `.js` files like I was before and `.ts` files with a new ruleset for `.ts`

Comment: With the above ruleset I added `"semi": "error"` just to check everything was working.  Right now I get no error in my `.ts` file or `.js` file for that rule.